# Unable to open connection to: localhost/127.0.0.1:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: android

My Android Studio 3.4.1 shows the error below (as in screenshot) when running the app

> Unable to open connection to: localhost/127.0.0.1:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

I have my android phone connected to my Windows 7 PC, but Android Studio still show the error. I did click on "Restart ADB server" but problem persists.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

**Use 10.0.2.2 to access your actual machine.**

When you use the emulator, `localhost (127.0.0.1)` refers to the device's own loopback service, not the one on your machine as you may expect.

You can use `10.0.2.2` to access your actual machine, it is an alias set up to help in development. You can read more from [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html)

Also, remember to access localhost from your real device your system and mobile need to connected to the same wifi/network.

Comment: i am not using an emulator, because My notebook becomes too slow. My notebook has only 4GB RAM.
So, i connect it to a real phone to test run the app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem on Ubuntu: but I found out also that my phone keep reconnecting in IDE.
Solution - just to give permission change things to the android studio folder.